# Can deleting a lot of your bad answers prevent you from being unbanned?

Tags: discussion, rules

I know that deleting a lot of your bad questions can get you banned, but can deleting a lot of your bad answers prevent you from getting unbanned?

Comment: If I were working for Stack Exchange, to prevent gaming, I'd want to keep the answer to this as confidential as I could.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by gameing?

Comment: I mean, I'd want to prevent people from learning how to bypass question or answer bans.

Comment: Deleted posts still count against you for the automatic post ban; for answers and questions

Comment: Can undeleting them undo it?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: If deleting bad posts gets you in trouble, wouldn't it make sense that doing so after you've been banned would get you into more trouble? The goal of it is to have you edit your answers to be more appropriate or helpful

Comment: @Nathan, the OP wants to know if things are different for answers. Deleting one's own questions is frowned upon as bad questions take time from people who're trying to help. Hence, bad questions should never have been posted to start with. (The same can be said for answers, but someone else might already have given a better answer, or the banned user might not know a better answer, and deleting also cleans up...)

Comment: I guess it could also depend on the question. If it is a closed question. I'm not sure if closed question gets auto deleted after some times, but there would be no way to ask in a better way an offtopic question. It has to be deleted in most case. It wouldn't make sense to get banned for cleaning up SO